# Получаю урон от своих пуль

Tags: unity3d

Есть функция получения урона:

```
 public override void ReceiveDamage()
    {
        Lives--;
        rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * 4.0F, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        if(lives == 0)
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);

        }
    }
```

Урон от пуль врагов я получаю:

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        Unit unit = collider.GetComponent<Unit>();
        Bullet bullet = collider.GetComponent<Bullet>();
        if (unit is Heart)
        {
            lives++;
        }

        if (unit)
            this.Die();
        if (bullet)
           this.ReceiveDamage();

    }


}
```

Однако проблема в том, что я получаю урон и от своих пуль, которые выпускает персонаж. Подскажите как прописать, чтобы свои пули не наносили урон?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставь врагам какой-нибудь тег, напримег Enemy. И сделай проверку, если у обьекта тег Enemy, то нанести урон. Хотя это не подойдет для сетевой игры...

Comment: Мне для учёбы нужно) Так что ваш вариант тоже подойдёт) Спасибо)

Comment: Лучше поставить тэг себе и проверять на отсутствие. А то врагов много, придется каждому ставить.

Comment: @Эникейщик For для того и существует :) и кстати, тег, а не тэг.

Comment: @VerNick 20 врагов выпустили по 20 пуль и сам игрок выстрелил 30 раз. Придется проверить 430 пуль на наличие 20 тэгов -> 8600 проверок. Если проверять на отсутствие собственного тэга, то проверок будет всего 430.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну вы так говорите, как будто проверка 1с занимает. Все это мнговенно пройдет. У меня огромная игра на javascript несколько тысяч проверок в секунду делает.

Comment: @VerNick Да неважно. Если можно сделать быстрее и проще, то зачем делать медленнее? Я, правда, там ошибся. У врагов же одинаковая метка, а не у каждого своя собственная. Так что разницы нет, проверять на наличие одной метки или на отсутствие другой.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы не попадать в своих и чужих назначаете им разные слои в Unity. Далее в настройках физики отключаете пересечение между слоями свой-свой, чужой-чужой. Ничего проверять не надо, все будет разрулено движком, объекты из одного слоя не будут знать о том что пересекаются, а вот между свой-чужой пересечение будет продолжать работать.

Только не забудьте когда создаете пули назначать им правильный слой, чтобы было ясно кем выпущено.

Если же надо чтобы можно было попасть в своего, то у пули заводится признак владельца, его заполняем ссылкой на источнк выстрела и при столкновении первым делом проверяете что вы не сами в себя выстрелили.

Comment: Вот более правильный ответ.